# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/winvenue/public_html/premieretheme.com/premieredl.php on line 17

Tags: php

This line is causing this error:

```
$st_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$secret_directory;
```

This is the variable:

```
$secret_directory = '/download/';
```

There was no error before and this started happening just now... Please help!

Comment: What's on the previous line

Comment: You're probably missing a semicolon on the previous line.

Comment: 14.$file_mime_type = 'application/x-rar-compressed' // the file mimes type
15.
16.

Comment: @user1316709: and as I said in my answer - there is no trailing `;`

Comment: In my experience, `unexpected T_VARIABLE` error happens when ou forget to enclose array variable in quotes or apostrophe, like `$var['name']` vs `$var[name]`.

Comment: Errors in PHP are usually very specific. The *parser* found a *syntax error*, a *variable* was *unexpected*, it happened in *file* at *line*... I do not mean to sound insensitive but when you get errors you should stop, read, and then think about it for a bit, before throwing in the towel.

Comment: @i--: if you try that - you'll see that your experience lies to you :-)

Comment: @zerkms - how can i argue with somebody who knows what comes before the actual sample of the code given ;) Of course I am wrong. Guess I got de-railed a bit by the second answer here, should have kept my mouth shut ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've missed `;` in the line 16th, right before `$st_dir = ...` line

Comment: Yup that did. Thanks a lot. Feel pretty stupid now :x

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, an "unexpected t_variable" error normally points to a line or two lower than where the error actually occurred. Usually, there's an unclosed apostrophe, or a missed semi-colon a few lines up, but the parser doesn't realize there's a problem until past where the error occurred.

Moral of the story, look above it!

Hope that helps.